# oracle query to retrieve closest and second closest future date based on the current date

Tags: oracle

I want to retrieve the closest and second closest future date based on the current date.
example :
current-date=28-07-2017

### dates to be retrieve

28-07-2017
29-07-2017

or followed top two dates which are closest to current date.

plzz help me out in writing this query in oracle

Comment: Your example is a little off. If you want FUTURE dates relative to current date then surely current date is not part of the output. Wouldn't that be the 29th and 30th ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select sysdate,sysdate + level "Dates" From   DUAL connect by level <= 1 ;
```

Comment: Any reason for downvote. Any mistake i made while addressing OP question. Please suggest,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the dense_rank analytic function, like so:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 ID, to_date('01/07/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, to_date('02/07/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 ID, to_date('02/07/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 4 ID, to_date('03/07/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 5 ID, to_date('04/07/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 6 ID, to_date('05/07/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 7 ID, to_date('06/07/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual)
SELECT ID, dt
FROM   (SELECT ID,
               dt,
               dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY dt) dr
        FROM   sample_data
        WHERE  dt >= to_date('01/07/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
WHERE  dr <= 2;

        ID DT
---------- -----------
         1 01/07/2017
         2 02/07/2017
         3 02/07/2017
```